# Laravel eloquent - constraining relationship query with an array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models `Content`, `ContentType`, and `Taxonomy`. Their relationships are set up like this:

**Content** model:

```
public function contentType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ContentType', 'ct_id');
}
public function taxonomies()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Taxonomy', 'taxonomical');
}
```

**ContentType** model:

```
public function contents()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Content', 'ct_id', 'id');
}
```

**Taxonomy**:

```
public function contents()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Content', 'taxonomical');
}
```

I am getting an array with taxonomies that I should use to filter the contents, the array could look like this one:

```
$taxonomiesArray =  ["Administrasjon", "Oslo", "Bane"]
```

With this kind of array I should make a query, where I would get only `contents`, that have all the `taxonomies` from that array, and are of `contentType` where column name is `intranet-post`, basically something like this:

```
$intranetTypePostID = ContentType::where('name', 'intranet-post')->pluck('id');
$contents = Content::where('ct_id', $contentType->id)->with(['taxonomies' => function($q) use ($userTaxonomies){
      $q->whereIn('slug', $userTaxonomies);
    }])->get();
```

But, how can I get only contents that have all the `taxonomies` that have the same slug as the values from the array `$taxonomiesArray`?

Comment: Look into [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: to pass `$taxonomiesArray` to callback use `...::with(['taxonomies' => function ($query) use ($taxonomiesArray) { ...`

Comment: yes, I know that, but how can I than get only the contents that have all the taxonomies from the array, if I pass the array like that and use whereIn, I will get all the contents that have at least one taxonomy that is contained in the array $taxonomiesArray, and that is not what I need

Comment: To get **where in** to match **all**, you could use [Matching all values in IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636061/matching-all-values-in-in-clause/11636084#11636084) in your `::with(`. I don't have time to test this out and to write an answer.