# Count all the rows that match all the values in IN clause

Tags: php, mysql

The values of my `$topics` are 1,2,3 i want to make a select query that is similar to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subtopics WHERE main_id = 1 AND main_id = 2 and main_id = 3..`

```
    function countTopics($mid,$forum){
    $topics = implode(', ', array_column($mid, 'main_id'));
    parse_str("id=1");
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM subtopics
               WHERE main_id   
                  IN ($topics)
                  GROUP BY main_id
                  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT $topics) = 3";
    $stmt = $forum->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        'mid' => $topics
    ));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $count = implode(', ', array_column($rows, 'COUNT(*)'));
    $_SESSION['topics_count'] = $count;
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having with this?

Comment: You have error ?  .. show the message. wrong result?  .. show a proper data sample and the expected  result.. what's your problem?

Comment: You may want to select the main_id as well so that you know which count is which.

Comment: Using `IN (1,2,3)` will give you the equivalent of `OR`, not `AND`.

Comment: No error but it doesn’t giving me a result..

Comment: im trying to get the number of topics base on the main id for example main id 1 contains 9 topics,main id 2 topics contains 3 and so on..Im having difficulty in using the where clause because the value of the main id is from another page so i store it in array and implode it..

Comment: Remove the `HAVING` clause.

`SELECT main_id, COUNT(*)
FROM subtopics
WHERE main_id  IN ($topics)
GROUP BY main_id`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636061/matching-all-values-in-in-clause...i found this a bit similar about my problem please help me in tweaking my code and add select count

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems with the code, your SQL doesn't need a HAVING clause, your trying to bind to a variable which isn't in the SQL statement...

```
function countTopics($mid,$forum){
    $topics = implode(', ', array_column($mid, 'main_id')); 
    $query = "SELECT main_id, COUNT(*) as countID
            FROM subtopics
            WHERE main_id IN ($topics)
            GROUP BY main_id";
    if ( $stmt = $forum->prepare($query) ) {
        if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $count = implode(', ', array_column($rows, 'countID'));
            $_SESSION['topics_count'] = $count;
        }
     }
}
```

Also you should check if the previous stage has worked - so 'if the statement prepare has worked' etc. Not sure what you would do if any of these fail, but that is down to your application design.

Not surewhat `$forum` is as it doesn't seem to be used and it would be more normal to return the value of the count and let the calling code decide what to do with the value.

You probably want to do something like...

```
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $_SESSION['topics_count'] = $rows;
```

and then later...

```
foreach ( $_SESSION['topics_count'] as $topic ) {
   echo $topic['main_id'].'-'.$topic['countID'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Update:

```
function countTopics($mid,$forum){
    $topics = implode(', ', array_column($mid, 'main_id')); 
    $query = "SELECT main_id, subtopic_id, COUNT(*) as countID
            FROM subtopics
            WHERE main_id IN ($topics)
            GROUP BY main_id, subtopic_id";
    if ( $stmt = $forum->prepare($query) ) {
        if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $_SESSION['topics_count'] = $rows;
        }
     }
}
```

I've added a column called 'subtopic_id', this may need to be changed depending on your database column name.  This will give rows as something like...

```
main_id   subtopic_id countID
1         1            12
1         2            6
1         3            10
2         6            1
2         11           3
```

This means you will have multiple rows for each main_id, but they will have each sub topic and a count for that subtopic.  If you want to output the data - you will have to use a loop, like the `foreach` above.

Comment: this is giving me all the different row counts but the problem is it is displaying all the different values how can i echo it separately                            topics                                                topic counts                                                              main topic1                                              9,5,2                                                     main topic2                                              9,5,2                                                            maintopic 3                                               9,5,2

Comment: expected output                                                                                                           main topic1                                              9                                                   main topic2                                              5                                                        maintopic 3                                               2

Comment: I'm not sure where you get the labels from the output from, but the issue is probably using the `implode` to set `$count`.  If you store the `$rows` value in `$_SESSION['topics_count']` then you can loop over the result set to output the data your after.  I've added some bits to the answer

Comment: This is what i been doing i used select query and fetch the main_id from another page and store it a session and implode it because it is giving me a array to string conversion error.And now im going to count all the rows in subtopics that is match with the main_id value and fetch the number of topics,by the way $forum is a variable for my connection.Can u please help me..sorry im new to php.

Comment: And I'm looping it in another page thats why i store it again in session

Comment: is there another way to do it?please help me

Comment: As your fetching data for a set of main_id's, then there is an array of data - 1 element per main_id value.  If you want the data for each sub-topic, then your query should probably be different - I will update the answer with some idea.