# MYSQL: how to return value from column that has relation to values in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Im struggling to articulate this, let alone execute in in MYSQL. How Do I return the userId X where userId.X and permissionId in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) ?

The below example should return 6.

```
MariaDB [mailserver]> select * from user2permission;
+--------------+--------+
| permissionId | userId |
+--------------+--------+ 
|            1 |      5 |
|            1 |      6 |
|            2 |      6 |
|            2 |      7 |
|            3 |      6 |
|            4 |      6 |
|            5 |      6 |
|            6 |      6 |
|            7 |      6 |
|            8 |      6 |
+--------------+--------+
```

Comment: Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, please.

Comment: `select userId from user2permission where permissionId in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);`  This should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching all values in IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636061/matching-all-values-in-in-clause)

Comment: I believe the standard docs for **ALL** can help you - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html

Comment: @Sudipta Mondal: No, `ALL` doesn't help with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of query can be written with the use of Group By clause and counting the instance as per the filteration applied in where clause

```
SELECT userId
FROM user2permission 
WHERE permissionId  IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
GROUP BY userId 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 8
```

Comment: Thank you Rizwan. This is the clarification i needed.

Comment: @dom Note that the implication here (not unreasonably) is that (userid,permissionid) is unique

Answer (score 0):

You want to only show users that have an entry for all required permissions. Two solutions spring to mind:

```
select *
from users
where userid in (select userid from user2permission where permissionid = 1)
  and userid in (select userid from user2permission where permissionid = 2)
  ...
```

and

```
select userid,
from user2permission
group by userid
having count(case when permissionid = 1 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when permissionid = 2 then 1 end) > 0
   ...
```

And when I say "spring" to mind, I mean exactly that = without much thinking :-) Rizwan's aggregation solution is what you should use.

Comment: Yeah, less springing maybe :-$